Unable to connect to SFTP server via DNS forwarding
I have a SFTP server setup on AWS Transfer Family. The server works fine when connecting via the designated endpoint AWS creates (Randomnumbers.server.transfer-us-east-1.amazonaws.com), however I am trying to route a connection through my personal domain hosted on Godaddy.
I am doing this via forwarding the address as, "sftp.myDomain.com -> AWS_SFTP_Endpoint", but the connection times out and I am unable to connect.
I have tried connecting via FileZilla with a username and keyfile, I have also tried changing the Godaddy forwarding from HTTP: to HTTPS (I don't think this changes anything).
I also attempted to route the name with "username@sftp.mydomain.com -> AWS_SFTP_Endpoint", but Godaddy isn't letting me.
I also set the AWS Transfer-Family server to use a custom DNS with the same name, to no avail.
There is probably a basic mistake I'm making here, thank you.

This is not a programming question.

What you are trying to do is described here: https://www.godaddy.com/help/add-a-cname-record-19236
But I cannot say this would work as GoDaddy expects both the alias sftp.mydomain.com and the s-randomnumbers.server.transfer-us-east-1.amazonaws.com entry to exist in your managed DNS records.
